# События клика jquery

Tags: jquery, события

У меня есть див, хочу отловить клик в нем. Про событие click знаю, когда в диве обычный текст то все работает как нужно, но я вывожу в нем кнопки соц сетей, на которые код не реагирует, как бы отловить клики по ним ?

Вот сам див:

```
<div class="shit"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone></g:plusone></div>
```

А вот код jq котоым я пытался сделать это:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
       $(".shit").click(function () {
             alert('click!');
         });
    } )
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае:

http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/

Смотреть после заголовка "+1 Tag Attributes"

Там есть колбэк функции. Туда можно назначить свои функции, которые отработают при "нажатии".

Вообще можно пробовать перехватывать события для ДИВ или ИФРЕЙМ объекта соцсети, но там на самом деле все индивидуально - событие могут прибить раньше, чем оно дойдет до вашего обработчика.

Универсально - наверно никак.

Comment: Случаем, не подскажете как всунуть callback в кнопочки Facebook? Конкретно интересует авторизация через Facebook...

Comment: Несовсем подходит, у меня просто не 1 кнопка там, но всеравно спасибо.

Comment: Я боюсь, что тот интерактив, который вы хотите для каждой "кнопочки" прийдется делать индивидуально, исходя из особенностей реализации...

Answer (score 1):

Можно исследовать в инструментах типа Opera Dragonfly или аналога в Хроме, как называются кнопочки (дивы это? какие у них классы?).
И заменить строчку на эту (например):

```
$(".shit div").click(function() {
```

Или может быть просто воспользоваться методом `children()`: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Исходя из слов

> У меня есть див, хочу отловить клик в нем.

У вас есть возможность тупо назначить клик-событие на все элементы, находящиеся внутри этого div'а, т.е. сделать просто `$(".shit *").click(function () {` - Этот код я не проверял, но смысл такой.

Comment: Не получаеться, наверно потому что кнопка генерируеться во фрейме, или может я что то не так делаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $(".shit").click(function () {
             alert('click!');
             return false;    
         });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Кнопки соцсетей выводятся в самом конце, поэтому на них click() может банально не успеть повеситься. Пользуйтесь [live](http://api.jquery.com/live)('click', function(){});

Comment: Все тот же эффект, видимо это и правда из за того что кнопка во фрейме. Ведь когда клацаю по любой другой части дива алерт срабатывает нормально, а когда по самой кнопке то ничего... 

Погуглил сейчас еще, там человек предложил попробывать наложить еще один див сверху и через него отслеживать клик. Может поможет кто с реализацией ? И вообще что тогда с кнопкой будет если прямо на ней еще один див будет ?

Comment: "может банально не успеть повеситься" © - не может такого быть, $(document).ready() срабатывает только после полной загрузки DOM